# In which cases you should block a user after a certain number of failed attempts?

Tags: authentication, account-lockout

I have a web app. Existing users can invite new users by sending a mail throw the web app.

If the user fails 4 consecutive times I block the acount for 5 minutes.

Currently there is no important information in the application.

The problem with the current policy is:

1. If a malicious user B want to block the user A he could try to log with A username's 4 times every 5 minutes. Then A couldn't log to the app.
2. I could block if the 4 fails cames from the same IP (and only block for that IP). But the malicious user can change his IP. I don't know how, but potentially he can fill my resources (because I have to take the count for each IP)
3. I can put captcha, but I'm not sure how much helps.

Can you help me? What can I read or do?

Comment: I think Max attempts exceeded -> show captcha for x attempts -> block account would do the job but wait for others' confirmation, also check this [question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477578/2595450)

Comment: You can add step like warning the user that the account is locked and ask them to check for the email send (or click button to request an email to get the reset url )

Comment: Captcha won't be very helpful if the attacker is human: captchas are meant to block *robots* not attacks. We've relied on it for a forum, and we still got the spammers, so an attacker A might still lock down a user account B the same way. *What are you actually trying to avoid by locking down the account?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to protect for the greater threat. You have 2 scenarios:

1. Malicious user/troll trying to deny service to a fellow user. This is a relatively common concern but is rare to see in practice
2. Attackers brute forcing accounts: Although your site may not have any data useful for an attacker the credentials themselves are as many users re-use passwords

Scenario 2 is, for most sites, far more likely and for that reason having a lockout policy is a good thing. Captcha (if implemented properly) would be useful to prevent bots from additional login attempts in scenario 2, after x number of attempts it would throw up a captcha screen, defeating a bot but humans could unlock it. Setting up alerts for repeated login failures is a smart idea so you can track this sort of thing, as is alerting users via email when it happens so a user can tell you whether it's them acting or not.

If you think scenario 1 is relatively likely for your site then being able to filter access from a particular set of IP addresses makes sense. Most malicious users don't have a botnet at their command that they'd use just to keep a user locked out, so you'd probably see a pattern. It would be harder to use this method against a sophisticated attacker though, just using TOR would be enough to defeat your filtering. One good bit of protection you could use for scenario 1 is in your login detail design, not allowing username sign-ins and using email addresses instead. That way if a troll doesn't like SmarterPerson1887 they'd have to know that user's email address, which is much less likely.

Comment: *"for that reason having a lockout policy is a good thing"* No. If you try to avoid force brute, then just make it too slow to be a threat (have your hash checking method take like 1second). Then, on a separate field, monitor your server resources and (temporary) ban clients that takes too much of it (no matter the reason).

Comment: That's an expensive method @Xenos, unless you just sleep the process. Plus, someone can just do concurrent attempts, so an attacker could still make attempts even if they are slower. Better to lock an account out so attackers move  on.

Comment: You shouldn't `sleep` since you'll anyway need the hashing check to be slow to avoid offline attack (if you DB gets breached). Parallel attempts won't be a threat either since the brute force would still take billions of years (assuming user chose a correct password). And your server is safe since you should already have counter measures against DDoS.

Comment: It sounds like you have your own answer @Xenos, why not put it down?

Comment: To bounce on your "Scenario 2", it's actually "never" happening in real world. Such brute force attackers usually don't target a single account. Instead, they list all users on the server (often a public info using memberlist and such) and try the top N-th most used passwords. You get far more results by doing so, and your locking down becomes useless (more often if it takes more than 5 minutes to try 5 passwords on all other accounts: you make a roll and won't get stopped).

Comment: I never said they'd be attacking a single account this way, which is why I said accounts.

Answer (score 2):

As asked, I'll make up my own answer.

> If a malicious user B want to block the user A he could try to log with A username's 4 times every 5 minutes. Then A couldn't log to the app.

That's the issue when locking accounts: you don't know if user is actually legitimate until they passed the login screen. So you cannot assume that user A is trying to log into account A. If it's not an issue for classic websites, it can be very problematic for webgames (I can lock another account right before attacking them, so they cannot defend themselves).

Usually, the reason why webmaster wants to lock down accounts is:

> I want to avoid a brute force

But if your database get breached, then an offline attack can be done and bypass your anti-brute force approach of locking accounts.

Plus, in my experience, attackers rarely brute force an account directly. Why? Because it requires quiet some time to get the right password (if it was chosen well). So attackers actually proceed another way around: they list all accounts on the server, and try most used passwords on each of these, account by account. **Somehow, instead of trying all passwords on one account, they try one password on all accounts.** Therefore, your anti-brute-force system is inefficient.

IMO, a better way to avoid brute force is simply to **make the hashing check longer (1second)**, by using enough iterations so it will take 1second (or so) per check. Doing this:

- If an attacker targets one account, they'll need billions of billions of years to breach it if the password was well chosen. If they make a hudge parallel attack, they'll still need billions of years
- You should already have some DDoS mitigation, so in case an attack takes too much resources on your server, then you'll be safe (it's another field that anti-brute-force accounts) For example, you can "prioritize" resources, giving them to logged in users first and leaving the half of the remainings to the non-logged in ones
- If an attacker tries one password on all accounts, they'll still need a lot of time to try the thousands of user accounts you have
- If your database get breached, offline attack will still need a lot of time, enough to let your users update their passwords
- It is stateless, so you won't have issue storing who made a login attempt, on which account, etc
- 1 second is short enough to be unnoticeable by regular users

Comment: I found here an intresting postgresql extension to do that! https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/auth-delay.html

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer You're not answering the OP's problem even if it's the same kind of problem: PosteGre extension will only lock **DB user** login attempts not website user logins. And that "one password for all accounts" will fail anyway on Postgre because: 1) logins are not public 2) they are very few DB user logins 3) their password is NOT simple

Comment: You are right. I am not answering any question. I am only commenting. It is posible to delegate the autentication to the database. With the apropiate security definitions (at table and row level), adding several store procedures and assigning one database user to each website user you can write a thin backend that pass almost all data request to the database (incluiding autentication). Of course the admin or superusers can not log throug the website. Returning to your answer with my comment I trying to say that samone else think that you are right about sleep the backend.